# Evaluation of Fortran's SUM(..) without temporary array?

Tags: fortran

Readability-wise, I find it preferable to write

```
momentum = sum( [( calculateMomentum(elements(i)), i=1, size(elements,1) )] )
```

over

```
momentum = 0.0d0
do i = 1, size(elements,1)
    momentum = momentum + calculateMomentum(elements(i))
end do
```

because the first version has the form of *defining* the value of `momentum`, while the second corresponds to a more lower-level accumulation instruction. The difference becomes more pronounced in real-world code with more arguments and possibly multiple indices.

However, the first version allocates a temporary array. As a human programmer I know, that it could be optimized away, so I was wondering if Fortran offers a syntax, that allows calculating the sum with neither an explicit loop nor a temporary array.

---

### Update

**No such construct.** It looks like there is no syntax, as what I was asking for. See [Vladimir F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64679079/2075630).

**It matters, but less than I thought.** I've made my own benchmark ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Pwxsrzwf), [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64678923/edit)) using matrix multiplication using several variants.

1. `C(i,j) = C(i,j) + A(i,k) * B(k,j)` was the slowest, probably due to the unnecessary array access in each step.
2. `C(i,j) =` sum( [(A(i,k) * B(k,j), k = 1, N)] )` was about 10-20% faster than (1), despite the temporary array.
3. `tmp = tmp + A(i,k) * B(k,j)`, i.e. using a temporary accumulator variable, was about 20% faster than (2).
4. `C = matmul(A,B)` was the fastest by far, compared to (3) by a factor of 25 for 500x500 matrices, growing to 50 for 2000x2000, while the relative speed of the other variants stayed roughly the same.

Bottom line: When the task cannot be expressed in optimized library- or intrinsic functions easily, the `sum` variant has viable performance, and should only be optimized away, if performance really matters to such a degree in that part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a temporary array will be allocated or net depends on the optimizations in the compiler. Stack allocation is almost free anyway. Copying the values will probably take longer.

The compiler may optimize unnecessary steps away if it can make sure the result will be the same. However, there is no special syntax for that. Fortran typically tries to stay far from the actual implementation and leaves a lot on the compiler.

Comment: There's an array constructor in the statement, but that can be avoided.

Comment: In Python there'd be `sum([f(x) for x in xs])` vs `sum(f(x) for x in xs)`. The first version creates an unnecessary list, like Fortran creates an unnecessary array. I was hoping to somehow ensure, that the intrinsic may do something more similar to `r = 0; do i=1,size(xs); r = r + f(xs(i)); end do` while maintaining the more declarative code style.

Comment: @kdb There is nothing like that in Fortran. No iterators, no closures, no lazy evaluation.

Comment: Technically, Fortran does not create an unnecessary array.  It is the compiler that you are using that is creating the temporary array.  Also, instead of guessing what gfortran is doing, you can look at intermediate dumps.   Try -fdump-tree-original and -fdump-tree-optimized (the trailing d might not be correct).  Finally, instead of trying to be clever, write the code in the manner that you desire, ie., `r = 0, do  i=1, size(xs); r = r + f(xs(i)); end do`

Comment: @evets Perhaps you wanted to address this to kdb?

Answer (score 2):

For experiment, I've tried this code (which computes the sum of inverse of `arr`).

```
program main
    use iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
    implicit none
    real(dp) val
    real(dp), allocatable :: arr(:)
    integer num, loop, i, t1, t2, trate

    num = 10**8
    arr = [( i, i = 1, num )]   !! L1

    do loop = 1, 10
        call system_clock( t1 )

        val = sum( [( testfunc( arr(i) ), i = 1, num )] )   !! L2

        call system_clock( t2, trate )
        print *, "val = ", val, " in ", (t2 - t1) / real(trate), " (s)"
    enddo

contains

function testfunc( x ) result( ret )
    real(dp), intent(in) :: x
    real(dp) :: ret

    ret = 1.0_dp / x
end

end program
```

Then, on my computer (mac2012), "gfortran-10 -O2 test.f90 && time ./a.out" gives

```
 val =    18.997896413852555       in    1.02999997      (s)
 val =    18.997896413852555       in    1.10099995      (s)
 val =    18.997896413852555       in    1.17600000      (s)
 ...

real    0m12.575s
user    0m8.142s
sys 0m4.387s
```

and "gfortran-10 -O3" gives

```
 val =    18.997896413852555       in   0.875000000      (s)
 val =    18.997896413852555       in   0.888000011      (s)
 val =    18.997896413852555       in   0.833000004      (s)
 ...

real    0m9.986s
user    0m5.738s
sys 0m4.210s
```

In both cases, the `htop` command shows ~1.5 GB allocated, which may be reasonable if lines L1 and L2 use a temporary array (each ~800 MB with ~0.3 s for allocation).

Because there is no syntax for creating "iterators", I've tried making `testfunc()` to be elemental (or impure elemental). The only difference here is the lines marked with `<--`.

```
program main
    use iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
    implicit none
    real(dp) val
    real(dp), allocatable :: arr(:)
    integer num, loop, i, t1, t2, trate

    num = 10**8

    arr = [( i, i = 1, num )]

    do loop = 1, 10
        call system_clock( t1 )

        val = sum( testfunc( arr ) )   !<--

        call system_clock( t2, trate )
        print *, "val = ", val, " in ", (t2 - t1) / real(trate), " (s)"
    enddo

contains

impure elemental &   !<--
function testfunc( x ) result( ret )
    real(dp), intent(in) :: x
    real(dp) :: ret

    ret = 1.0_dp / x
end

end program
```

Then, "gfortran-10 -O2" gives

```
 val =    18.997896413852555       in   0.437000006      (s)
 val =    18.997896413852555       in   0.453999996      (s)
 val =    18.997896413852555       in   0.437999994      (s)
 ...
real    0m5.946s
user    0m5.069s
sys 0m0.842s
```

and "gfortran-10 -O3" gives

```
 val =    18.997896413852555       in   0.225999996      (s)
 val =    18.997896413852555       in   0.252000004      (s)
 val =    18.997896413852555       in   0.246999994      (s)
 ...
real    0m3.909s
user    0m3.009s
sys 0m0.867s
```

The `htop` command show ~800 MB, so it seems only `arr` is allocated.

For comparison, the following code calculates `val` with an explicit do-loop (using a scalar version of `testfunc()`)

```
val = 0
do i = 1, num
    val = val + testfunc( arr(i) )
enddo
```

which gave the same timing with the second code with `elemental` + `testfunc(arr)` above (on my mac).

In all the above code, the `-Ofast` option resulted in a runtime error (`Illegal instruction`). But this was due to the line L1 (`arr = [( i, i = 1, num )]`). If I allocate `arr` beforehand and populate it with an explicit loop, `-Ofast` also worked without problem (giving almost the same timing with `-O3` in this case).

Comment: So what is the answer?

Comment: maybe "there is no iterator in the standard"...?

Comment: So why did you not put that i to your answer? Maybe I am just bitching and people do upvote your answer and do not upvote mine but in my opinion answer should  first and formost answer the question asked. And then show inteesting experiments about performance. Perhaps I am just od and grumpy.

Comment: @VladimirF Hi, I just thought that your (first) answer already gave the rigorous answer (from the standard), which I think should be accepted (cc: @kdd), so I added some experiments from a different angle (because OP seemed to have interest in related codes also). Anyway, I feel "elemental"  is a very useful feature.

Comment: OK, I think it is always good to say the salient point in a new answer, even it has been said before.

Answer (score 1):

If you make `calculateMomentum` and elemental function, then it can be used for both scalar values and for arrays

for example with:

```
    elemental function calculateMomentum(obj, v) result(p)
    class(body), intent(in) :: obj
    real, intent(in) :: v
    real :: p
        p = obj%mass * v
    end function
```

you can apply the above to an array of `v`

```
integer::i
type(body) :: ball
real, allocatable :: v(:), p(:)
real :: tot_p
allocate(v(10))
v = [ (10+i, i=1, 10) ]
p = calculateMomentum(ball, v)
tot_p = sum(p)
```

having an intermediate array to hold the values is advantageous because it keeps the data close by (probably within the cache-line) and the `sum()` function would be as quick as it can be.

imagine the type `body` as follows for example

```
    type body
        real :: mass
    end type
```